# What’s up with Hela’s portal?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

When Hela first appears to Thor and Loki, she steps through a portal crawling with greenish-black energy. What’s unclear to me is the nature of the portal.

- The fact that the color scheme matches Hela’s strongly suggests that it’s something she did. But if it’s a facet of Hela’s powers, why was Thor so worried that she’d get swept up in the Bifrost (she could just make a portal to Asgard)? And why not use it all in the rest of the film?
- If it’s not Hela’s doing, why would she appear where Thor and Loki were? Wouldn’t she just be stuck in…wherever? Why would a portal bring her to Norway, of all places?

What exactly is going on with that portal? Is it Hela’s doing, or something else?

Comment: I thought it was Odin's doing, and the before, evil Odin was closer in likeness to Hela. Since he imprisoned her until his death, she returned at the place where he died, which I guess she wasn't certain was going to be Norway and not Asgard.

Comment: It's possible that Odin banished Hela in Norway. Or, death of Odin triggered some kind of rupture in the pocket dimension she was trapped into.

Comment: “she could just make a portal to Asgard” — maybe not. Maybe she was imprisoned on earth, and you’re seeing her exit her prison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hela was trapped in her realm without any kind of access to the other realms. Like the angels realm, this was also blocked by the OdinForce and Uur construction of those 2 realms. So when Odin died, she was free to go through the door(?) which lets you walk between realms. Asgard is an exception as it is hidden in the space thanks to Odin Force again. Which is why after Odin's Death, they could get to Asgard through a wormhole. Hela felt the Odinforce disappearing and simply traced it back to the last of its presence. And for the colour scheme, it is hell. Can be red like shown everywhere else or black/green as her colour theme since she ruled over it. Hela can walk through mortal plains from wherever she is.

Comment: Do you have any sources from this, as this was unclear from the film, was this said in some form of interview or extended features?

Comment: The earlier answer was mine and whoever edited it clearly doesnt know that her name was Hel. Hela was adopted in the new series and the movie because it confuses with Hell. Which is where she rules. And this is from the arc where Angela fight with her and Hel's handmaiden, Leah, helps Angela to defeat her. She tells the story then. About how these people traverse all the planes with the 2 exception being Asgard and Heven.

Comment: You should be editing your answer with the account you used before. As I said in the comments to the other answer, this answer is asking about the Marvel cinematic universe, NOT the comics. As far as I can tell, [Hel is a region](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Hel) who's ruler is Hela.

Comment: I posted the answer as a guest. And OP did not mention anywhere that this was Marvel Cinematic Universe only. Secondly, even if it was, nothing wrong with using the traditional entities right? I wont call Odin Force as omnipotent and supreme to everything else in the universe just because it was said so in the Avengers.

Comment: The OP did mention it was MCU, by including the MCU tag and not the Comics tag (you can read the tag wikis [here, MCU](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/marvel-cinematic-universe/info) and [here, comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/comics/info) ). And yes, there is something wrong because it's out of the scope of the answer, they're clearly separate canons. [You can merge your two accounts by following this link here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: @SagarSaxena Sadly, yes, this question is about the MCU, so answers based on the actual Norse gods or any other version of Thor/Loki/Hel stories won't be what the OP (original poster) is looking for. Sorry :-(